# UIViewController life cycle

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Result:

```
2014-05-12 11:17:24.891 viewController[2206:60b] init

2014-05-12 11:17:24.910 viewController[2206:60b] loadView

2014-05-12 11:17:24.911 viewController[2206:60b] viewDidLoad!

2014-05-12 11:17:24.912 viewController[2206:60b] viewWillAppear

2014-05-12 11:17:24.916 viewController[2206:60b] dealloc

2014-05-12 11:17:24.982 viewController[2206:60b] viewDidAppear
```

Why dealloc method between viewWillAppear method and viewDidAppear method?

```
 - (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {

        NSLog(@"init");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    NSLog(@"loadView");
    [super loadView];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad!");
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: looks strange and abnormal

Comment: Are you sure those are all from the same view controller instance? BTW - Never call `[super loadView]` from an implementation of `loadView`. And don't implement `loadView` unless you actually setup the view.

Comment: Also show the code that creates and displays this view controller.

Comment: The method init and loadView does not achieve,the result same!

Comment: @user3349116 You are not using ARC?

Comment: @Ved Obviously not since he is able to call `[super dealloc]`.

Comment: YES, not using ARC,Memory is manually released.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered unless you show how you create this controller, and how you show it (or otherwise access its view).

Comment: Are you sure all the log in the same view controller? Try to log the `self` and to see what will happen.

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [view release];
    [nav release];
    return YES;
}
Is such!

Comment: YES, all the log in the same view controller!I want to understand the life cycle of viewController

Comment: The method dealloc log `self` address was changed!

Comment: @user3349116 please put your code in the question, not comments.

Comment: I believe the question is a not problem, waste our time indeed, discard should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments:

> The method dealloc log self address was changed! –  user3349116

You're seeing logs from different instances of the view controller. Include `self` in your logs when you're trying to trace activity like this. And make sure not to break the view controller while you're doing it (your loadView implementation will probably mean you have nothing to display on the screen).

In any case, the view controller life cycle is well documented and in most cases pretty obvious.